# How to use representer in older version ( version <= 0.11) of ruamel.yaml

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

```
ruamel.yaml.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(type(None), represent)
```

Works fine in the `0.14.X` version of ruamel.yaml package

How to use same functionality in older version ( **<= 0.11** ) of ruamel.yaml package  or alternative way to use in previous version of package?

here is example of my program

```
def represent(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'NULL')

ruamel.yaml.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(type(None), represent)

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(input.yaml)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, output.yaml)
```

while running above code getting below error

`ruamel.yaml.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(type(None), represent_none)\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RoundTripRepresenter'`

Comment: Why would you want to use ruamel.yaml<=0.11

Comment: ruamel.yaml ( Version: 0.10.11) is default package in our custom ISO,

Comment: Is there any chance to get some more information about that custom ISO (possible via email)? Just out of interest in how/where my packages are being used.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of `ruamel.yaml` the `RoundTripRepresenter` (defined in `representer.py`) was not imported into `main.py` and thus not available via `__init__.py` (which does
 `from ruamel.yaml.main import *`)

So you should just import it from the source:

```
from ruamel.yaml.representer import RoundTripRepresenter

RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(type(None), represent)
```